# Is there a good way to Promise.all an array of objects which has a property as promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

If I have an array of promises, I can simply use `Promise.all` to wait for them all.

But when I have an array of objects, each of them having some properties that are promises, is there a good way to deal with it?

Example:

```
const files=urlOfFiles.map(url=>({
  data: fetch(url).then(r=>r.blob()),
  name: url.split('/').pop()
}))
//what to do here to convert each file.data to blob?
//like Promise.all(files,'data') or something else
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of mapping the data to an array of objects, you could map it to an array of promises that resolve to objects:

```
const promises = urlOfFiles
    .map(url => fetch(url)
        // r.blob() returns a promise, so resolve that first.
        .then(r => r.blob())
        // Wrap object in parentheses to tell the parser that it is an
        // object literal rather than a function body.
        .then(blob => ({
            data: blob,
            name: url.split('/').pop()
        })))

Promise.all(promises).then(files => /* Use fetched files */)
```

Comment: But if a file object has more than one properties that are promise, I need to write a nested callback?

Comment: That'll definitely make it more complex. An array of `Promise.all()`'s might work (something similar to this answer, but using `Promise.all(...)` instead of `fetch(url)`).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
const files = urlOfFiles.map(url=>
  fetch(url).then(r=> ({
    data: r.blob()
    name: url.split('/').pop()
  })
  ))
Promise.all(files)
```

Comment: The same as commented to another answer: resulting array of object will not have blob as data but rather promise.

Answer (score 1):

With multiple async properties of the return value you could use nested `Promise.all` (if other async results rely on response of `fetch`) or as Tulir suggested; start off with a `Promise.all([fetch(url),other])...`:

```
Promise.all(
  urlOfFiles.map(
    url=>
      fetch(url)
      .then(
        r=>
          Promise.all([//return multiple async and sync results
            r.blob(),
            Promise.resolve("Other async"),
            url.split('/').pop()
          ])
      )
      .then(
        ([data,other,name])=>({//return the object
          data,
          other,
          name
        })
      )
  )
)
.then(
  files=>
    console.log("files:",files)
);
```